# OnChanged even't isn't firing (AJAX raiting control) inside a datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm using the latest ajax toolkit version. I've tried to put the rating control in a datalist, but the OnChanged event for some reason isn't firing. 
That's the normal ASPX.NET page:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataListEpisodes" runat="server" Style="position: relative; bottom: 330px;" Visible="False" RepeatColumns="1" OnItemDataBound="DataListEpisodes_ItemDataBound" DataKeyField="EpisodeID" OnItemCommand="DataListEpisodes_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="ImageEpisodeImage" class="EpisodeImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("EpisodeImage", "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original{0}") %>' />
                    </td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelEpisodeNumber" runat="server" Style="font-family: Gotham Ultra; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"
                        Text='<%# Eval("SeasonNumber", "Season {0}") + ", " + Eval ("EpisodeNumber", "Episode {0}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelEpisodeName" Style="font-family: Proxima Nova Semibold; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EpisodeName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" class="LabelOverview" Text='<%# Bind("EpisodeOverview") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddEpisode" class="ButtonAddEpisode" runat="server" Text="Add Episode To Watch History" CommandName="AddEpisode" />
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemoveEpisode" class="ButtonAddEpisode" runat="server" Text="Remove Episode From Watch History" CommandName="RemoveEpisode" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonWatchListAdd" class="ButtonEpisodeWatchList" runat="server" Text="Add Episode To Future Watch List" CommandName="AddWatchList" />

                    **<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="Rating1" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" style="position: relative;right: 301px;top: 16px;" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
                                StarCssClass="Star" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" WaitingStarCssClass="Star">
                            </ajaxToolkit:Rating>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Rating1" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>**
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and that's the codebehind:

```
    protected void OnRatingChanged(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = ((sender as AjaxControlToolkit.Rating).NamingContainer as DataListItem).ItemIndex;

    int RatingChosed = Rating1.CurrentRating;
    int EpisodeID = Convert.ToInt32(DataListEpisodes.DataKeys[rowIndex].ToString());
```

}

Thank you if someone can help me :D

Comment: Where I would start to troubleshoot this is remove the update panel temporarily, and see if it gets fired.  Container controls do bubble events up though, so it could be the rating control s triggering a command in the datalist too....

Comment: Tried this, isn't working... but thank you

Comment: What isn't working?  Try adding an ItemCommand event on the data list, and see if that is being called when issuing a rating.